# Traversing Json and return only some attributes

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

Is it possible to search object attributes and access all in the same level?

I have steps objects which can cosist from 1 to n attributes (directions steps). I would like to choose only attributes values with in the same level:

```
"travel_mode" : "TRANSIT"
```

It means I could access for example name attribute which is not available in the level where travkl_mode is walking

```
                 "steps" : [
                    {
                       "distance" : {
                          "text" : "0,3 km",
                          "value" : 285
                       },
                       "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                    },
                    {
                       "distance" : {
                          "text" : "13 m",
                          "value" : 13
                       },
                       "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                    }
                 ],
                 "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "2,5 km",
                    "value" : 2506
                 },
                    "departure_stop" : {
                       "location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1157011,
                          "lng" : 11.6602402
                       },
                       "name" : "Mönchbergstraße"
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "TRANSIT"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0,2 km",
                    "value" : 230
                 },
                       "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                    },
                    {
                       "distance" : {
                          "text" : "15 m",
                          "value" : 15
                       },
                       "duration" : {
                          "text" : "1 Minute",
                          "value" : 16
                       },
                       "end_location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1175728,
                          "lng" : 11.6371798
                       },
                       "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eLinks\u003c/b\u003e Richtung \u003cb\u003eHeinrich-Wieland-Straße\u003c/b\u003e abbiegen",
                       "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                       "polyline" : {
                          "points" : "u~tdHu{_fAZH"
                       },
                       "start_location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1177065,
                          "lng" : 11.6372328
                       },
                       "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                    },
                    {
                       "distance" : {
                          "text" : "35 m",
                          "value" : 35
                       },
                       "duration" : {
                          "text" : "1 Minute",
                          "value" : 24
                       },
                       "end_location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1176498,
                          "lng" : 11.6367222
                       },
                       "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eRechts\u003c/b\u003e abbiegen auf \u003cb\u003eHeinrich-Wieland-Straße\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eDas Ziel befindet sich auf der linken Seite.\u003c/div\u003e",
                       "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                       "polyline" : {
                          "points" : "y}tdHk{_fAAHK|@AR"
                       },
                       "start_location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1175728,
                          "lng" : 11.6371798
                       },
                       "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                    }
                 ],
                 "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
              }
           ],
           "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
           "via_waypoint" : []
        }
     ],
```

I tried something like that:

```
        var answer = JSON.parse(body), busName;

        for(key in answer){                               
            if(key.indexOf("name") != -1){             
                busName = answer[key];                
                break;                                  
            }
        }
```

but Im getting undefined value in the busName

Comment: I don't think your json is valid.  I pasted it into https://jsonformatter.org/json-editor and I had to make several guesses at what you may have wanted to get it to validate.  You have to get that right before you start trying to access keys.  If you just console.log(answer) what do you get?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to ask.... so you're saying every object where travel mode is 'TRANSIT' you want to access the stop name? or for any travel mode in any object, you want to access the name of any other object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make a stab at helping you with validated json.

```
var answer = {
  "steps": [
    {
    "distance": {
      "text": "0,3 km",
      "value": 285
    },
    "travel_mode": "WALKING"
  },
  {
    "distance": {
      "text": "13 m",
      "value": 13
    },
    "travel_mode": "WALKING"
  },
  {
    "distance": {
      "text": "2,5 km",
      "value": 2506
    },
    "departure_stop": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 48.1157011,
        "lng": 11.6602402
      },
      "name": "Mönchbergstraße"
    },
    "travel_mode": "TRANSIT"
  },
  {
    "distance": {
      "text": "0,2 km",
      "value": 230
    },
    "travel_mode": "WALKING"
  },
  {
    "distance": {
      "text": "15 m",
      "value": 15
    },
    "duration": {
      "text": "1 Minute",
      "value": 16
    },
    "end_location": {
      "lat": 48.1175728,
      "lng": 11.6371798
    },
    "html_instructions": "<b>Links</b> Richtung <b>Heinrich-Wieland-Straße</b> abbiegen",
    "maneuver": "turn-left",
    "polyline": {
      "points": "u~tdHu{_fAZH"
    },
    "start_location": {
      "lat": 48.1177065,
      "lng": 11.6372328
    },
    "travel_mode": "WALKING"
  },
  {
    "distance": {
      "text": "35 m",
      "value": 35
    },
    "duration": {
      "text": "1 Minute",
      "value": 24
    },
    "end_location": {
      "lat": 48.1176498,
      "lng": 11.6367222
    },
    "html_instructions": "<b>Rechts</b> abbiegen auf <b>Heinrich-Wieland-Straße</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Das Ziel befindet sich auf der linken Seite.</div>",
    "maneuver": "turn-right",
    "polyline": {
      "points": "y}tdHk{_fAAHK|@AR"
    },
    "start_location": {
      "lat": 48.1175728,
      "lng": 11.6371798
    },
    "travel_mode": "WALKING"
  }
 ],
 "traffic_speed_entry": [],
 "via_waypoint": []
};
```

Paste that json into [online json editor](https://jsonformatter.org/json-editor) and see if it gives you the structure you expect.  You will have to fix how you are generating your json as it is not valid.

With my json :

```
console.log(answer.steps[2].departure_stop.name); // ​​​​​Mönchbergstraße​​​​​

for (key in answer.steps) {
  if (answer.steps[key].departure_stop) {
    console.log(answer.steps[key].departure_stop.name); // ​​​​​Mönchbergstraße

    // do what you want with the answer.steps[key] object here
    //  answer.steps[key].travel_mode
  }
}
```

This above assumes that all departure_stop objects have a "name" key.  If they don't you should do a null check for that too before trying to access its value.

```
for (key in answer.steps) {
  if (answer.steps[key].travel_mode && answer.steps[key].travel_mode === "TRANSIT") {

    // do what you want with the answer.steps[key] object here
    console.log(answer.steps[key].departure_stop.name); // ​​​​​Mönchbergstraße
  }
}
```

I hope this helps, it is unclear what exactly you are trying to accomplish.